Transfinite recursion(Thomas Jech)
Let $G$ be a function in the universal class of sets. There exists unique $F$ from $Ord$ to $ran(G)$ such that
$$F(\alpha) = G(F_{|\alpha})$$
Proof:
The function $F$ is defined as follows:
$$F(\alpha) = x \Leftrightarrow \exists (a)_{\alpha}: \forall \epsilon \in \alpha: a_\epsilon = G((a)_\epsilon)\quad(*)$$
So, the sequence is built up "recursively" as promised by using $G$. But it is unclear if this is a function or if the domain is $Ord$.
To show this is a function, let $(a)_\alpha$ and $(b)_\alpha$ be the sequence satisfies the condition for $\alpha$. Then, by inductive proof, it follows that $(a)_\alpha = (b)_\alpha$. So, $F$ must be a function.
My question:

What's the approach for the successor step and limit step?

The latter part where we use induction again to show that $F$ is unique is trivial.

For the limit case. Let all $\epsilon < \alpha$ admit some sequence satisfying $(*)$ where $\alpha$ is limit ordinal. Since $\bigcup \alpha = \alpha$, we can just union all $\epsilon$-sequence. This must make sense because we have proved that such sequence formation depends only on its length[when we prove $F$ is a function]. Thus, the union is "smaller sequence replaced by larger". There's no duplicates.
The successor case is done by taking $F(\alpha)$ in the previous step and trivially form the sequence $(a)_{\alpha + 1}$ by combining $F(\alpha)$ and the union(just like in the limit case).
